# WordPress Product Add-Ons Plugin Not Showing on Frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

**I posted this on the [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198421/product-add-ons-not-showing-on-frontend) yesterday and I am crossposting it here as we are desperate for help.**

The agency I work for purchased the Product Add-Ons plugin from WooThemes a few days ago for use on a client's website.

Upon installing and activating the plugin, I cannot get it to display on the product pages.

The plugin works in terms of adding the Add-Ons in the backend, however I am unable to get it to display in the frontend.

I have added different tiers to the Add-Ons, for testing purposes, however that has delivered no successful results.

I have been trying to rectify the issue, however I have had no such luck. I have read through the documentation, however I still cannot seem to rectify the problem.

Epson WorkForce DS-30 Add-On Information Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDLc6.jpg

Epson WorkForce DS-30 Product page Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/juioG.jpg

I have since populated all applicable products with the add-on information, and the product pages are still coming up without them (see screenshots above).

I have contacted WooThemes directly, and as of yet have had no response. As far as I am aware, it has not been forwarded onto a specialist ninja as of yet and the client is getting rather impatient with the website not going live, and frankly I don't blame them. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to rectify the issue so I hand over to you.

I would appreciate any help you guys could provide.

**EDIT:** I have now had a response from WooThemes, and the response I got was that it was a theme issue. I have since contacted Themify about their ShopDock theme and I will keep this updated for anybody else who may be experiencing the same/similar issues.

Comment: 1. Try with a default theme. 2. Verify your theme has the `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` hook in its add to cart templates. 3. If the hook is present: check your console for Javascript errors. 4. If you still have issues, contact Woo support.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks for your response. After crossposting this to the WordPress Support Forum for WooCommerce, I finally got a response. Apparently it's some sort of conflict with the theme.

I have contacted the theme supplier to see whether there is anything that they can do and if not, I shall try your suggestion (although, that might be one of their troubleshooting methods).

Comment: That was my guess. Points 1-3 were to try to isolate the problem to your theme (and potentially other plugins). I would check your theme for outdated templates, which would explain why you might be missing that all-important hook.

Comment: It turns out that the single-products.php page, which is not an original ShopDock php page, was present and that was causing problems. The themify team informed me of that and renamed the file as to not cause any conflicts within the website.

It's now running perfectly fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Add the following short code in your code.
Or add via Elementor.

```
[yith_wapo_show_options]
```

[Reference:](https://support.yithemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018840334-The-addons-are-not-shown-on-the-single-product-page)